# XNA BoundingBox to vertex collision detection

Tags: xna, collision-detection, collision, vertex, bounding-box

We're building a 3D FPS game for our school's project, and we're having a little problem doing precise collision detection.
In fact, we are using this library http://dev.theomader.com/projects/collidable-model/ to detect them, as it is pretty efficient. However, the default "box" we have to send to the methods in this library to test for a collision is a BoundingSphere, but we want to test for a collision with a BoundingBox (as an example, the player would be represented as a BoundingBox and we would test it with the model)

I've came to a point where I can send a boundingbox to the library by modifying the code, but at this point, I don't know what to do so that the boundingbox actually acts as one. In fact at the moment I calculate collisions as if it was a boundingSphere. See by yourself:

```
private bool nodeCollisions(BoundingBox b, BspNode node)
{
    float radius = Vector3.Distance(b.Min, b.Max) / 2;
    float squaredBoundingSphereRadius = radius * radius;
    Vector3 center = b.Min + (b.Max - b.Min) / 2;

    foreach (int i in node.faces)
    {
        Face face = mGeometry.faces[i];
        Vector3 pos1, pos2, pos3;
        pos1 = mGeometry.vertices[face.v1];
        pos2 = mGeometry.vertices[face.v2];
        pos3 = mGeometry.vertices[face.v3];

        // check collision with triangle bounding sphere first
        if (b.Intersects(face.boundingSphere) == false)
        {
            continue;
        }

        Vector3 closestPoint = closestPointInTriangle(center, pos1, pos2, pos3);
        float squaredDist = (closestPoint - center).LengthSquared();
        if (squaredDist <= squaredBoundingSphereRadius)
        {
            return true;
        }

    }

    return false;
}
```

But this leads to a big problem: we can't have a player being taller than large, as it all depends on the "radius" of the boundingBox.

So my question is, how can I modify this code so that the collision is actually properly tested with the boundingbox?

Thank you.